# "by afternoon" or "by the afternoon"

Tags: articles

I was reading the book *Advanced Grammar in Use* (Martin Hewings) and there was an example:

> - I’ll be there by (the) morning / ... by (the) evening.
>
> *but* …
>
> - ... by the afternoon, *not*  … by afternoon)

But when I compare "by afternoon"with "by the afternoon" using Ludwig, the phrase "by afternoon" is not just acceptable, but actually more common. Some examples are:

> - By afternoon, Steve still hadn't arrived.
> - By afternoon, the entire army was exhausted.

So I wonder: are both the phrases acceptable and do they have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I prefer the sound of 'by the afternoon' or 'by that afternoon', [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+the+afternoon+we%2Cby+afternoon+we&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20afternoon%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20afternoon%20we%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cby%20the%20afternoon%20we%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cby%20afternoon%20we%3B%2Cc0) (several tokens checked; no false positives) show that 'by afternoon' seems quite as idiomatic as 'by the afternoon' and was probably the preferred version between the 1940s and 1970s:

[image]

Comment: It sounds okay to me as is.  Maybe it's a UK-US difference.

Comment: Quite possibly. Re-reading, I get an unavoidable connotation of sandwiches on the lawn in a pleasant garden. Been watching too much Poirot / Father Brown ....

Comment: Sounds lovely.  But were there deadlines and ultimatums in that environment?

Comment: The sandwiches disappear quickly.